# Forecasts for the S&P 500?

Tags: equities, statistics, forecasting, spx

Would anyone know of any monthly forecasts for the S&P 500, historical over a long time periods.

Websites like estimize provide forecasts of all sorts of things likes stocks and the balance of trade, but I can't seem to find any S&P 500 forecasts

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge there is no long-running survey of expectations for stock indices. Even if it did exist, you would be better served by using S&P 500 futures, which go back to the 80s.

Answer (score 0):

EEO on Bloomberg provides quarterly estimates of earnings and annual estimates of multiples (nothing monthly from what I can see). Alternatively, just collect the forecasts from the sellside as they're updated. I don't think they have any value whatsoever but you might find a way to productively use them.